# JSON Error,When you calling Multiple Web service with the help of AFNetworking for uploading and down laoding data for whole application in a loop

Tags: ios, sqlite, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I am implementing Sync All process for my iOS App...Application saves lot of data in SQLite and when you press a button.. for Sync.. Fetch All Data from SQlite and uploaded to the server we are calling multiple web services in loop and after uploading we are calling web services for downloading of data (Zip files, pdf etc.). then Of the uploading web service Got exception 
"Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.) UserInfo=0x10b509f10 {NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}
"

But If I am calling only uploading web services then i got success message.

I am using for calling Web Service AFNetworking Classes wrapper by my blocks classes.